# req.session is not working on another route

Tags: node.js, express, session

Im trying to use sessions in express but its not working properly

In

```
app.get("/mod", async function (req, res) {
     var sess = req.session;
      console.log(sess)
})
```

The output is

```
Session {
cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true }, 
uid: '1234123123',
utag: 'Tag_etc',
uav: 'other stuff'
}
```

But if I use

```
     app.get("/approve", async function (req, res) {
            var sess = req.session;
            console.log(sess)
})
```

The Output is

```
Session {
    cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true }
}
```

without the other stuff I need. Any Idea why this is happening?

Thank you for your help :D

Comment: you've gotta give more code and context. is this after refreshing? no refresh? redirect? is your app.use correct? how are you saving the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and send a response: `res.send("hello")`
This would terminate the connection correctly and write the session